# Data modeling with Redis python

Tags: python, redis, crud, datamodel

I am currently using a mongodb as a database for my application. I am interested in replacing it with REDIS. Hence, I am interested in defining data models for my application which can perform basic CRUD operations and search entities based on various keys. I am pretty new to Redis and looking for examples in python which can help me define data models for my application and suggest different approaches to perform the transition.

Example - Assume it's a basic chat client-server application where the user logs in and can chat with any number of people. I would need to track what is the user's ID, how many people is a given user chatting with, probably the top 5 groups who have maximum participants. Based on such queries, can someone point me to some links or define sample data model in python for Redis.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rom

Comment: https://redislabs.com/ebook/redis-in-action